# "A TV reality show I would like to see '' means the TV show that I wanna do?

Tags: would-rather

I confused for that because I wrote the TV show I like but my friends told me that was the one I wanna do.
Give me explaination

Answer (score 1):

You are right.

"I would like to see something" doesn't mean the same as "I would like to do something".

If you "do a tv show", that means you are an actor or presenter. We might say "a tv show I'd like to be on"

If you "see a tv show" you are at home. We might say "watch a tv show" instead of "see".

By the way, "wanna" is how we *say* "want to", but don't use it in writing.